# CSS3 - Curve like header band as background

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage which is requiring a curve like background (starting and ending point having same height and in center we need a curve with larger height. background-width:980px;). Can anyone help me in CSS3?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: At least show a mockup of some kind. A picture speaks a thousand words and all that.

Comment: It is not allowing me to add, since i need reputation